# How to detect if an item is dropped near an armor stand?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-data-packs

I'm trying to make a sort of shrine system where a player can drop a set number of items, say five gold ingots near a shrine, which is a block with an armor stand inside of it, and be given a beneficial effects for a few minutes. Not completely sure how to do that though. Can someone help?

Answer (score 1):

Thats is quite tricky, I might suggest just using a hopper in front of the shrine to pick up the blocks. When detected by a redstone comparator, it activates a command block to give that player whatever effect needed.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample command that can detect when items are near an armour stand:

```
execute at <stand> if entity @e[type=item,distance=..5,nbt={Item:{id:"minecraft:gold_ingot",Count:5b}}] run ...
```

Rundown:

- `at <stand>`: At the location of the armour stand...
  (Fill in with a selector for your armour stand.)
- `if entity @e[…]`: if there is any entity that:

  - `type=item` is an item entity, and
  - `distance=..5` is within a 5-block radius, and
  - `nbt={Item:{id:"minecraft:gold_ingot",Count:5b}}` the item is a gold ingot with 5 count stack...
- `run ...` then run a command.